# Symmetrized Kronecker Product in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math, matrix

I would like to verify the correctness of my implementation of the symmetric Kronecker operator, but I have had trouble finding any library or otherwise "correct" implementations. The one implementation I have managed to find is in MATLAB from [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/361452-symmetric-kronecker-product-in-matlab), but I think it is incorrect:

```
function M = sk(A,B)
    % symmetric kronecker product for two square matrices, each of size nxn
    n = size(A,1);
    U = eye(n^2);
    a = reshape(1:n^2,n,n);
    b = a';
    U = U + U(b(:),:);
    c = tril(a);
    c = c(:);
    c(c==0) = [];
    U = U(c,:);
    U(U==1) = sqrt(2);
    U(U==2) = 1;
    M = (1/2)*U*kron(A,B)*U';
end
```

The calculation of the non-zero indices of  matrix U agree with mine, but I think the fourth to last line should be `U(U==1) = 1/sqrt(2)` and that the second to last line should be `M = (1/2)*U*(kron(A,B)+kron(B,A))*U';`. The definition of the symmetric Kronecker product which we both appear to have used is from "On the Nesterov-Todd Direction in Semidefinite Programming", by Todd, Toh, and Tutuncu.

Comment: While the question per se is OK, I really doubt anyone will read the entire paper to corroborate your results. I hope you find someone that has peexisting knowledge on this, but its a bit unlikely. Perhaps you should ask in math.stackexchange.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure whether to ask on here or in math.stackexchange. I wasn't expecting anyone to read the paper, just hoping that someone would know of some obscure math library that has an implementation of the symmetric Kronecker operator with which I could verify my solution. Many libraries such as numpy have the Kronecker operator, but not the symmetric version.

Comment: I suggest asking in there too. In here you may get a software solution, in there you may have someone to verify that your code is right mathematically. That said, I also think its 1/sqrt(2)